# Keyboard keys swapped after reboot: "Alt" and "Super" (Lubuntu 18.04, lxde)

Tags: keyboard, lubuntu, keyboard-layout, lxde

After having rebooted and connected, as always, my Goldtouch keyboard to my laptop, the keys "Alt" and "Super" were swapped on both sides (i.e. on the right-hand side "Alt Gr" with the right "Super"-key.

On my lxde-desktop (Lubuntu 18.04), there doesn't seem to be a proper depiction of every key assigned to the current keyboard connected.

While the problem persists on my connected keyboard, on the native laptop keyboard, which works simultaneously,the keys respond correctly.

The [information](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Lubuntu/Keyboard) given by the Lubuntu (LXDE) documentation was not helpful in my case, since it is too generic and doesn't provide hints how to solve the aforementioned issue(s).
Probably something similar to the [gnome-surface keyboard](https://eastmanreference.com/how-to-change-the-keyboard-layout-in-ubuntu) like in standard Ubuntu would be useful, but also command-line approaches are welcome. Nevertheless, it would be nice to be able to display a map of the keyboard layout in order to visualize what is actually going on (I hope there is a possibility on LXDE).

For example, on my bottom-right panel there is no symbol for seeing the current keyboard-layout key-by-key, as I had it earlier in Ubuntu.

**I'd like to find a way how to see the current keyboard-layout key-by-key for ALL keyboards connected, and also be able to change the keys for each of them, if necessary.**
In the case of my externally connected keyboard from Goldtouch, I'd like to change the swapped assignment of the super and "alt" keys.
To be honest, I don't even understand where this change came from in the first place.

Thanks for your help in advance.
Below, you'll find the details of my OS and keyboard-related aspects.

**My OS-info:**

```
Linux andylu-ThinkPad-Edge-E130 5.0.0-37-generic #40~18.04.1-Ubuntu SMP Thu Nov 14 12:06:39 UTC 2019 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux
```

**My hardware info filtered for keyboard and similar information:**

```
(base) andylu@andylu-ThinkPad-Edge-E130:~$ hwinfo | grep -i key
    0000-0000 : keyboard
    0000-0000 : keyboard
 thinkpad_hotkey: /devices/LNXSYSTM:00/LNXSYBUS:00/PNP0A08:00/device:01/PNP0C09:00/LEN0068:00
i/o:1 0x0000 - 0x0000 (0x01) "keyboard"
i/o:1 0x0000 - 0x0000 (0x01) "keyboard"
    product = "Goldtouch USB Keyboard"
    product = "Goldtouch USB Keyboard"
  B: KEY=10000000000000 0
  B: KEY=10000000000000 0
  N: Name="AT Translated Set 2 keyboard"
  B: KEY=402000000 3803078f800d001 feffffdfffefffff fffffffffffffffe
  N: Name="Lite-On Technology Corp. Goldtouch USB Keyboard"
  B: KEY=1000000000007 ff9f207ac14057ff febeffdfffefffff fffffffffffffffe
  N: Name="Lite-On Technology Corp. Goldtouch USB Keyboard Consumer Control"
  B: KEY=300ff 0 0 483ffff17aff32d bf54444600000000 1 130c730b17c000 267bfad9415fed 9e168000004400 10000002
  N: Name="Lite-On Technology Corp. Goldtouch USB Keyboard System Control"
  B: KEY=c000 10000000000000 0
  N: Name="Lite-On Technology Corp. Goldtouch USB Keyboard"
  B: KEY=100000300000000 0 0 0
  B: KEY=e520 10000 0 0 0 0
  B: KEY=10040 0 18040000 0 50000000000000 0 1701b02102004 c000280051115000 10e000000000000 0
  B: KEY=70000 0 0 0 0
  B: KEY=100000 0 0 0
  B: KEY=3e000b00000000 0 0 0
  B: KEY=1f0000 0 0 0 0
  key = 00100000000000000000000000000000
  key = 00100000000000000000000000000000
bus = 17, name = AT Translated Set 2 keyboard
  key = 000000040200000003803078f800d001feffffdfffeffffffffffffffffffffe
bus = 3, name = Lite-On Technology Corp. Goldtouch USB Keyboard
  key = 0001000000000007ff9f207ac14057fffebeffdfffeffffffffffffffffffffe
bus = 3, name = Lite-On Technology Corp. Goldtouch USB Keyboard Consumer Control
  key = 00000000000300ff000000000000000000000000000000000483ffff17aff32dbf54444600000000000000000000000100130c730b17c00000267bfad9415fed009e1680000044000000000010000002
bus = 3, name = Lite-On Technology Corp. Goldtouch USB Keyboard System Control
  key = 000000000000c00000100000000000000000000000000000
bus = 3, name = Lite-On Technology Corp. Goldtouch USB Keyboard
  key = 0100000300000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000
  key = 000000000000e52000000000000100000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000
  key = 0000000000010040000000000000000000000000180400000000000000000000005000000000000000000000000000000001701b02102004c000280051115000010e0000000000000000000000000000
  key = 00000000000700000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000
  key = 0000000000100000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000
  key = 003e000b00000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000
  key = 00000000001f00000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000
  E: ID_INPUT_KEY=1
  E: KEY=10000000000000 0
  E: ID_INPUT_KEY=1
  E: ID_INPUT_KEY=1
  E: KEY=3e000b00000000 0 0 0
  E: ID_INPUT_KEY=1
  E: DRIVER=thinkpad_hotkey
  E: ID_INPUT_KEY=1
  E: KEY=10000000000000 0
  E: ID_INPUT_KEY=1
  E: ID_MODEL=Goldtouch_USB_Keyboard
  E: ID_MODEL_ENC=Goldtouch\x20USB\x20Keyboard
  E: ID_SERIAL=Lite-On_Technology_Corp._Goldtouch_USB_Keyboard
  E: HID_NAME=Lite-On Technology Corp. Goldtouch USB Keyboard
  E: ID_INPUT_KEY=1
  E: ID_INPUT_KEYBOARD=1
  E: ID_MODEL=Goldtouch_USB_Keyboard
  E: ID_MODEL_ENC=Goldtouch\x20USB\x20Keyboard
  E: ID_SERIAL=Lite-On_Technology_Corp._Goldtouch_USB_Keyboard
  E: KEY=1000000000007 ff9f207ac14057ff febeffdfffefffff fffffffffffffffe
  E: NAME="Lite-On Technology Corp. Goldtouch USB Keyboard"
  S: input/by-id/usb-Lite-On_Technology_Corp._Goldtouch_USB_Keyboard-event-kbd
  E: DEVLINKS=/dev/input/by-path/pci-0000:00:14.0-usb-0:1:1.0-event-kbd /dev/input/by-id/usb-Lite-On_Technology_Corp._Goldtouch_USB_Keyboard-event-kbd
  E: ID_INPUT_KEY=1
  E: ID_INPUT_KEYBOARD=1
  E: ID_MODEL=Goldtouch_USB_Keyboard
  E: ID_MODEL_ENC=Goldtouch\x20USB\x20Keyboard
  E: ID_SERIAL=Lite-On_Technology_Corp._Goldtouch_USB_Keyboard
  E: HID_NAME=Lite-On Technology Corp. Goldtouch USB Keyboard
  E: ID_INPUT_KEY=1
  E: ID_MODEL=Goldtouch_USB_Keyboard
  E: ID_MODEL_ENC=Goldtouch\x20USB\x20Keyboard
  E: ID_SERIAL=Lite-On_Technology_Corp._Goldtouch_USB_Keyboard
  E: KEY=c000 10000000000000 0
  E: NAME="Lite-On Technology Corp. Goldtouch USB Keyboard System Control"
  S: input/by-id/usb-Lite-On_Technology_Corp._Goldtouch_USB_Keyboard-event-if01
  E: DEVLINKS=/dev/input/by-id/usb-Lite-On_Technology_Corp._Goldtouch_USB_Keyboard-event-if01 /dev/input/by-path/pci-0000:00:14.0-usb-0:1:1.1-event
  E: ID_INPUT_KEY=1
  E: ID_MODEL=Goldtouch_USB_Keyboard
  E: ID_MODEL_ENC=Goldtouch\x20USB\x20Keyboard
  E: ID_SERIAL=Lite-On_Technology_Corp._Goldtouch_USB_Keyboard
  E: ID_INPUT_KEY=1
  E: ID_MODEL=Goldtouch_USB_Keyboard
  E: ID_MODEL_ENC=Goldtouch\x20USB\x20Keyboard
  E: ID_SERIAL=Lite-On_Technology_Corp._Goldtouch_USB_Keyboard
  E: KEY=100000300000000 0 0 0
  E: NAME="Lite-On Technology Corp. Goldtouch USB Keyboard"
  S: input/by-id/usb-Lite-On_Technology_Corp._Goldtouch_USB_Keyboard-event-if01
  E: DEVLINKS=/dev/input/by-id/usb-Lite-On_Technology_Corp._Goldtouch_USB_Keyboard-event-if01 /dev/input/by-path/pci-0000:00:14.0-usb-0:1:1.1-event
  E: ID_INPUT_KEY=1
  E: ID_MODEL=Goldtouch_USB_Keyboard
  E: ID_MODEL_ENC=Goldtouch\x20USB\x20Keyboard
  E: ID_SERIAL=Lite-On_Technology_Corp._Goldtouch_USB_Keyboard
  E: ID_INPUT_KEY=1
  E: ID_MODEL=Goldtouch_USB_Keyboard
  E: ID_MODEL_ENC=Goldtouch\x20USB\x20Keyboard
  E: ID_SERIAL=Lite-On_Technology_Corp._Goldtouch_USB_Keyboard
  E: KEY=300ff 0 0 483ffff17aff32d bf54444600000000 1 130c730b17c000 267bfad9415fed 9e168000004400 10000002
  E: NAME="Lite-On Technology Corp. Goldtouch USB Keyboard Consumer Control"
  S: input/by-id/usb-Lite-On_Technology_Corp._Goldtouch_USB_Keyboard-event-if01
  E: DEVLINKS=/dev/input/by-id/usb-Lite-On_Technology_Corp._Goldtouch_USB_Keyboard-event-if01 /dev/input/by-path/pci-0000:00:14.0-usb-0:1:1.1-event
  E: ID_INPUT_KEY=1
  E: ID_MODEL=Goldtouch_USB_Keyboard
  E: ID_MODEL_ENC=Goldtouch\x20USB\x20Keyboard
  E: ID_SERIAL=Lite-On_Technology_Corp._Goldtouch_USB_Keyboard
  E: KEY=1f0000 0 0 0 0
  E: ID_INPUT_KEY=1
  E: KEY=100000 0 0 0
  E: ID_INPUT_KEY=1
  E: ID_INPUT_KEY=1
  E: ID_INPUT_KEYBOARD=1
  E: KEY=402000000 3803078f800d001 feffffdfffefffff fffffffffffffffe
  E: NAME="AT Translated Set 2 keyboard"
  E: ID_INPUT_KEY=1
  E: ID_INPUT_KEYBOARD=1
  E: LIBINPUT_ATTR_KEYBOARD_INTEGRATION=internal
  E: KEY=e520 10000 0 0 0 0
  E: KEY=70000 0 0 0 0
  E: ID_INPUT_KEY=1
  E: KEY=10040 0 18040000 0 50000000000000 0 1701b02102004 c000280051115000 10e000000000000 0
  E: ID_INPUT_KEY=1
  E: KEYBOARD_KEY_01=screenlock
  E: KEYBOARD_KEY_02=battery
  E: KEYBOARD_KEY_03=sleep
  E: KEYBOARD_KEY_04=wlan
  E: KEYBOARD_KEY_06=switchvideomode
  E: KEYBOARD_KEY_07=f21
  E: KEYBOARD_KEY_08=f24
  E: KEYBOARD_KEY_0b=suspend
  E: KEYBOARD_KEY_0f=brightnessup
  E: KEYBOARD_KEY_10=brightnessdown
  E: KEYBOARD_KEY_11=kbdillumtoggle
  E: KEYBOARD_KEY_13=zoom
  E: KEYBOARD_KEY_14=volumeup
  E: KEYBOARD_KEY_15=volumedown
  E: KEYBOARD_KEY_16=mute
  E: KEYBOARD_KEY_17=prog1
  E: KEYBOARD_KEY_1a=f20
  links: /dev/input/by-id/usb-Lite-On_Technology_Corp._Goldtouch_USB_Keyboard-event-kbd, /dev/input/by-path/pci-0000:00:14.0-usb-0:1:1.0-event-kbd
  links: /dev/input/by-id/usb-Lite-On_Technology_Corp._Goldtouch_USB_Keyboard-event-if01, /dev/input/by-path/pci-0000:00:14.0-usb-0:1:1.1-event
  links: /dev/input/by-id/usb-Lite-On_Technology_Corp._Goldtouch_USB_Keyboard-event-if01, /dev/input/by-path/pci-0000:00:14.0-usb-0:1:1.1-event
  links: /dev/input/by-id/usb-Lite-On_Technology_Corp._Goldtouch_USB_Keyboard-event-if01, /dev/input/by-path/pci-0000:00:14.0-usb-0:1:1.1-event
  BIOS Keyboard LED Status:
06: None 00.0: 0900 Keyboard controller
  Model: "Keyboard controller"
  WLAN authentication modes: open sharedkey wpa-psk wpa-eap
37: USB 00.0: 10800 Keyboard
  Hardware Class: keyboard
  Model: "Lite-On Goldtouch USB Keyboard"
  Device: usb 0x006e "Goldtouch USB Keyboard"
  Device Files: /dev/input/event4, /dev/input/by-id/usb-Lite-On_Technology_Corp._Goldtouch_USB_Keyboard-event-kbd, /dev/input/by-path/pci-0000:00:14.0-usb-0:1:1.0-event-kbd
  Model: "Lite-On Goldtouch USB Keyboard"
  Device: usb 0x006e "Goldtouch USB Keyboard"
  Device Files: /dev/input/event7, /dev/input/by-id/usb-Lite-On_Technology_Corp._Goldtouch_USB_Keyboard-event-if01, /dev/input/by-path/pci-0000:00:14.0-usb-0:1:1.1-event
45: PS/2 00.0: 10800 Keyboard
  Hardware Class: keyboard
  Model: "AT Translated Set 2 keyboard"
  Device: 0x0001 "AT Translated Set 2 keyboard"
```

Comment: The page https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Lubuntu/Keyboard **does** apply to LXDE and Lubuntu so I'm confused by what you mean by "*gnome-surface*".  LXDE & Lubuntu uses no part of GTK3 used by GNOME Shell, or what you're thinking about. That page was specifically written (and edited) by Lubuntu members for LXDE & openbox only.

Comment: I realized that I haven't expressed myself clearly, wherefore I rewrote the paragraph related to your concern. Thanks for the notice. For any further contribution, I'll be thankful.

Answer (score 0):

On goldtouch keyboards there is a physical switch on the back of the keyboard labeled mac/pc which switches alt and super and a few other keys.  I used keymon on Ubuntu to help track down that my keys were backwards.